# Как поставить картинку в Embed не через ссылку? Disnake

Tags: python, discord.py

````
    async def hug(self, inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, member: disnake.Member):

        num = randint(0, 2)
        if member == inter.author:
            member = "самого(у) себя"
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title=f"{inter.author} обнял(а) {member}."
        ).set_image(url=f"../../gifs/hug{num}.gif")
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed) ```

set_image(url=f"../../gifs/hug{num}.gif") - ругается что должна быть ссылка
````

Answer (score 0):

Всё исправил!  Надо было сделать file="path"

Comment: Уточните ваш ответ.  Нужно было вызвать `set_image(file=f"../../gifs/hug{num}.gif")` вместо `set_image(url=...)`?